# Do power adaptors need cooling?

Tags: power, cooling, charger

I am thinking about moving all my wires into a box under my desk drawers and was wondering about the power adaptors for monitors and my xbox, laptop etc.. Do they need cooling or can it just get really hot in the box and you would not need to worry.  Currently they are exposed to open air with ventilation.

Comment: This is just from my experience, but I've noticed that some older bricks get a bit warm but not so warm I can't hold them, so I don't think they can.

Comment: @Chipperyman "I think they can" is never a helpful answer. Here's some background info: if an adapter is made for that product, it will not exceed safety limits, and its okay. If an adapter has the same plug, same voltage, but different amperage as the device uses, the adapter has to work extra hard to convert the voltage into the proper wattage, causing the adapter to become hotter and possibly exceeding safety limits.

Comment: Alternative -- attach a wire mesh "cable tray" to the underside of your desk ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against this, as many heat sources in a small area will add to the heat which may cause the plastic around the wires to melt and cause wires to short out leading to fire.

Even though one adapter that is properly used, will most likely not be a problem, having a place with almost no air ventilation never is a good thing.

Trapped heat will build up to a certain degree. Even though it may still be fine, its a caution you should avoid.

Do note: when you use an adapter that is not exactly made for your product, it can cause any adapter to become hotter than normally. Now by itself this is not so much of a problem, but it can cause the adapter to have a shorter lifecycle and as pointed out earlier in this answer, increase the heat in your small box.

If, however, that box is not fully closed and does have openings in it for air, you're totally fine.